# I want to change my password across an email. I have tried answers given on this forum but still unable to do it

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with the class which is given below. I have made setters, getters and constructor as required.

```
public class Contact {
    int ID;
    String Name;
    String Email;
    String Password;
    String DateofBirth;
    String Address;
    String PhoneNumber;
```

//This is my DatabaseHandler.java file

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {    
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;         
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";             
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";         
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL="email";         
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";   
    private static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";           
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";   
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
```

I am updating password across an email but the application crashes. The following code is learn from this forum and it crashes also.

```
public void updatePassword(Contact contact){                             
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();                        
    String sql="SELECT KEY_ID FROM " +TABLE_CONTACTS + "KEY_EMAIL"+"=?"; 
    db.rawQuery("UPDATE"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +" SET " +                      
            KEY_PASSWORD+"="+contact.getPassword()+"WHERE"+              
            KEY_EMAIL+"=?",new String[]{contact.getEmail()});            
}
```

Comment: When you get the crash there will be a stacktrace in the Logcat window of Android Studio. Edit your question to include it, please

Answer (score 0):

Try doing :-

```
public void updatePassword(Contact contact){                             
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();                                 
    db.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_CONTACTS +" SET " +                      
                KEY_PASSWORD+"=? WHERE "+              
                KEY_EMAIL+"=?",new String[]{contact.getPassword(),contact.getEmail()});
}
```

This adds space after UPDATE keyword and before WHERE keyword and has two bound parameters for the variables. The sql variable is not need, it does nothing.

Comment: Its still crashes but i found the following answer and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
public void updatePassword(String email, String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
    db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_EMAIL+" = ?",new String[] { email });
    db.close();
}
```